# Setting path of the Native Library for DllImport on Mono for Mac

Tags: pinvoke, environment-variables, monomac

The code I am porting to Mono for Mac, calls into a unmanaged C++ library. On the Mac I have ported our unmanaged library into a Framework(unfortunately our Build process only allows it to be compiled as a Framework and not as a dylib). In Mono I have set up a post build step in my project to copy the Framework file next to the built app.

But when a P/Invoke into this dll I get a DllNotFound exception. I read through the [Mono Interop Wiki](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) and it seems P/Invoke on Mono will only look at the locations pointed to by the DYLD_* environment variables and the current directory is not in the search path. When I copied the Framework to /Library/Frameworks, my P/Invoke calls worked fine, but I would prefer my Framework files to be present next to the App and not in /Library/Frameworks.

I tried adding the current working directory to the DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH environment variable in my code before I do any P/Invoke calls, but the System.Environment namespace has limited functionality on Mono for Mac and Getting or Setting environment variables is not supported.

Is there anyway I can keep my Framework files next to the App and still be abel to P/Invoke?

Comment: Are you saying that `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` doesn't work in Mono?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's split this into two questions: how to set environment variables and how to bundle native frameworks in a MonoMac application.

**Setting Environment Variables**

You can set environment variables in the `LSEnvironment` section of your application's `Info.plist`, like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
            <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.yourcompany.TableViewTest</string>
            <key>CFBundleName</key>
            <string>TableViewTest2</string>
            <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
            <string>10.6</string>
            <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
            <string>MainMenu</string>
            <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
            <string>NSApplication</string>
            <key>LSEnvironment</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>Foo</key>
                    <string>Bar</string>
            </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

It seems like to have to manually edit that file once and add at least one environment variable.

The file is automatically created by MonoDevelop, so all you have to do is to add the `LSEnvironment` section.

After that, you can edit them in MonoDevelop: go to project options, "Mac OS X Application", "Advanced".

**Bundling Native Frameworks in a MonoMac Application**

You don't need to set any environment variables to bundle a native framework in a MonoMac Application, there's a much easier and cleaner way to do it, which is also similar to how things work in Objective C.

I created a small [test applications](https://github.com/baulig/Provcon-Faust/tree/cf7d136230eccbfb02179f79917c8598ee1a6b05/TestFramework), which bundles a framework both in a native Objective C application and in a MonoMac one.

The first thing you need to do is bundle your framework with the app.  There currently is no way of doing this automatically in MonoDevelop, so you need to manually copy the files or use some post-build script (see `copy-framework.sh` in my example).

I would recommend to put the framework into `YourApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/YourFramework.framework` as that's how XCode handles it; see also [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html).

To reference a library inside your application bundle, you can use `@executable_path' (see the [dyld man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html)).

I would recommend to create an app.config file using `<dllmap>`, so you don't need to put any pathnames into your code, thus making it easier to change framework versions.  For instance:

```
    <configuration>
       <dllmap dll="TestFramework" target="@executable_path/../Frameworks/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework" />
     </configuration>
```

If the actual library inside your framework starts with `lib` or ends with `.so` / `.dylib`, then you must specify that name (the above dllmap won't file `TestFramework.framework/libTestFramework.dylib`, for instance).  This is a bug in Mono, which I just fixed.

Comment: This method works when I give the full path to my app in the Environment variable but fails if I try to give relative paths from what should be the current working directory. When I did some more debugging in my App I found that the cwd is set to / . Is there anyway I can give the path to my app without having to hardcode it?

Comment: You could either replace the startup file `YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp` with a shell script or modify the one that's created by MonoDevelop (https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/build/MacOSX/monostub.m).
However, I think I just found a much better and cleaner way of doing this, lemme quickly test it, then I'll update my answer with it.

Comment: Ok, there actually is a clean and easy way of doing this - just need to quickly fix a bug in Mono for you to get this to work.