# Using dllmap on monomac

Tags: sqlite, mono, dylib, monomac, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to use a custom build of sqlite with MonoMac, effectively as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536843/including-custom-dll-and-dylib-in-monomac-app).

However, using dllmap doesn't seem to be working.

My custom dylib is being deployed into `[myapp.app]/Contents/Frameworks/mycustomlib.dylib`

Output of `otool -L mycustomlib.dylib` looks correct:

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks/mycustomlib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

My `myapp.exe.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="sqlite3" target="@executable_path/../Frameworks/mycustomlib.dylib" os="!windows" />
</configuration>
```

And I have verified that it is being copied alongside `myapp.exe` in `[MyApp.app]/Contents/MonoBundle`.

I can force this to work by recompiling `Mono.Data.Sqlite` and directly replacing the reference to `sqlite3` with `mycustomlib`. However, the dllmap route is much nicer.

What am I missing? How can I debug this?

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue? I'm totally stuck on this. In my case my dylib ended up in Resources (though I wonder how did you get it into the "Frameworks" folder?). Are you using Xamarin Studio?

Comment: ok, I just realized that dropping the dylib into NativeReferences creates that Frameworks folder, though I'm not sure how you would access it in Debug, would you also have a Frameworks folder? my dllmap still doesn't work :P

Comment: Never got the dllmap to work. As for the /Frameworks folder, I had a post-build shell script that created the directory structure and moved the files in there

Answer (score 1):

Move the dllmap configuration from `myapp.exe.config` to a new `Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll.config` file for the remaps to take effect.

Comment: I recall that I tried that and it didn't work... But I don't remember the specifics. Upvote for you, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem, I just encountered the same issue when trying to use sqlcipher rather than the packaged sqlite3 and this is what did the trick for me.