# How do I bundle a framework in a monodevelop project?

Tags: macos, frameworks, mono, sdl

I'm having big trouble understanding how I would be able to bundle a framework(SDL) with my app in order to avoid having the user manually install it. The problem is that I can't figure out how to make mono look for frameworks in the .app folder.

I've seen several posts on changing the install path of a framework and then linking it with an x-code project but I've yet to find anything that covers this when using mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently answered a related question here:
[P/Invoke into .framework files on Mono Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777299/p-invoke-into-framework-files-on-mono-mac/12947468#12947468)
and [Setting path of the Native Library for DllImport on Mono for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834141/setting-path-of-the-native-library-for-dllimport-on-mono-for-mac).

See the section titled "Bundling Native Frameworks in a MonoMac Application" in my reply to that 2nd question.

Comment: Thank you, I found this shortly after the question was posted and it solved my problem. In the case of SDL we used the tao library and just had to change its existing config file in order to find SDL, thanks!